# Create a list of Key-Value pair

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, key

I have these facts:

```
name(john),
name(mary),
name(jack),
```

When I "iterate" all facts I find for every name something like a rating(a number). I want that rating to be paired with the name something like 2-john or john-2, store them in a list and sort the list based on the number. How can I do that in ProLog?

```
name(PersonsName), findRating(PersonsName, Rating), fail.
```

Comment: `setof(V-K, ( name(K), rating(K, V) ), VKs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@false gave the correct answer in the comment:

```
setof(V-K, ( name(K), rating(K, V) ), VKs)
```

Personal side joke for @false, that was more than `:-`.  `:)`

I will just expand on it here for those needing the missing parts.

First the facts need to be facts, i.e.

`name(john),`  is not a fact because it ends with a `,`. A fact needs to end with a period (`.`).

Next facts are needed to associate a rating with the person.

```
rating(john,2).
rating(mary,3).
rating(jack,4).
```

Now for [setof/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)

The signature of setof/3 is `setof(+Template, +Goal, -Set)`

`Goal` is the query that will return the needed data, in this case goal is `name(K), rating(K,V)`, but since that is more than one statement it is wrapped in `()` becoming `( name(K), rating(K, V) )`

Example run:

```
?- name(Name),rating(Name,Rating).
Name = john,
Rating = 2 ;
Name = mary,
Rating = 3 ;
Name = jack,
Rating = 4.
```

While that gives us the data needed it is not in a format that is useful and returns the results one by one.

`Template` is the format of the data in the result, in this case `V-K`, where `V` for `Value` is the rating and `K` for `Key` is the key. The result will be like `2-john`.

Here is an example of what we have so far demonstrated with a query and example run:

```
rating(V-K) :-
    name(K),
    rating(K,V).

?- rating(Ratings).
Ratings = 2-john ;
Ratings = 3-mary ;
Ratings = 4-jack.
```

Notice that the results are cumming back in the correct format but still not in a list.

`Set` is what is collected into the result.

Since you asked for a sorted result, `setof/3` is used instead of `bagof/3`. As noted in `setof/3`: `sorts the result using sort/2 to get a sorted list of alternatives without duplicates.`

To make it easier to run the query instead of typing the entire setof/3 each time, just put it into a predicate.

```
ratings(VKs) :-
    setof(V-K,(name(K),rating(K,V)),VKs).
```

---

Complete code.

```
name(john).
name(mary).
name(jack).

rating(john,2).
rating(mary,3).
rating(jack,4).

ratings(VKs) :-
    setof(V-K,(name(K),rating(K,V)),VKs).
```

---

Example run:

```
?- ratings(VKs).
VKs = [2-john, 3-mary, 4-jack].
```

---

Note: This could also be done using [library(assoc): Association lists](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc) but for this problem using `setof/3` is so much more concise.